# Im trying to make a machine that would learn to play the matches game and use the best possible moves, but I cant get my program to work

Tags: machine-learning

```
import random
matches = 11
remove_count = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
def AI_move():
    choices = random.choice(remove_count)
    print(choices)
    matches = matches - choices
    if matches <= 1:
        print("game over, AI won")
        remove_count.append(choices)
def user_move():
    user_choice = input("Your move:")
    if user_choice < 1 or user_choice > 3:
        print("error")
        user_choice = input("Your move:")
    matches = matches - user_choice
    if matches <= 1:
        print("game over, user won")
        remove_count.remove(choices)
def game():
    while matches >1:
        AI_move()
        if matches <= 1:
            print("game over, AI won")
            remove_count.append(choices)
        else:
            user_move()
        if matches <= 1:
                print("game over, user won")
                remove_count.remove(choices)
        exit()

game()
```

basically the game is that one party discards from 1 to 3 matches and then the other does as well, when the matches are at 1 or 0, the party who made the last move before reaching this moment wins, the game starts at 11 matches

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I cant get my program to work"?

Comment: oh yeah sorry, basically, when I try to execute it, it just instantly says program finished when it didn't output anything, I need it to output the machine answer and then let me input my answer and then after that let the machine output its answer again etc